# How to connect to a remote Windows machine to execute commands using python?

Tags: python, windows, sockets, wmi, remote-server

I am new to Python and I am trying to make a script that connects to a remote windows machine and execute commands there and test ports connectivity.

Here is the code that I am writing but it is not working. Basically, I want to and it returns with the local machine data, not the remote one.

```
import wmi
import os
import subprocess
import re
import socket, sys

def main():

     host="remotemachine"
     username="adminaam"
     password="passpass!"
     server =connects(host, username, password)
     s = socket.socket()
     s.settimeout(5)
     print server.run_remote('hostname')

class connects:

    def __init__(self, host, username, password, s = socket.socket()):
        self.host=host
        self.username=username
        self.password=password
        self.s=s

        try:
            self.connection= wmi.WMI(self.host, user=self.username, password=self.password)
            self.s.connect(('10.10.10.3', 25))
            print "Connection established"
        except:
            print "Could not connect to machine"


   def run_remote(self, cmd, async=False, minimized=True):
       call=subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT )
       print call

main()
```

Comment: It is important to prefix the domain in front of the username. For example `username = r"EUR\adminaam"`

Answer (score 12):

You can connect one computer to another computer in a network by using these two methods:

- Use WMI library.
- Netuse method.

---

#### WMI

Here is the example to connect using wmi module:

```
ip = '192.168.1.13'
username = 'username'
password = 'password'
from socket import *
try:
    print("Establishing connection to %s" %ip)
    connection = wmi.WMI(ip, user=username, password=password)
    print("Connection established")
except wmi.x_wmi:
    print("Your Username and Password of "+getfqdn(ip)+" are wrong.")
```

---

#### netuse

The second method is to use netuse module.

By Netuse, you can connect to remote computer. And you can access all data of the remote computer. It is possible in the following two ways:

1. Connect by virtual connection.

   ```
   import win32api
   import win32net
   ip = '192.168.1.18'
   username = 'ram'
   password = 'ram@123'

   use_dict={}
   use_dict['remote']=unicode('\\\\192.168.1.18\C$')
   use_dict['password']=unicode(password)
   use_dict['username']=unicode(username)
   win32net.NetUseAdd(None, 2, use_dict)
   ```

   To disconnect:

   ```
   import win32api
   import win32net
   win32net.NetUseDel('\\\\192.168.1.18',username,win32net.USE_FORCE)
   ```
2. Mount remote computer drive in local system.

   ```
   import win32api
   import win32net
   import win32netcon,win32wnet

   username='user'
   password='psw'

   try:
       win32wnet.WNetAddConnection2(win32netcon.RESOURCETYPE_DISK, 'Z:','\\\\192.168.1.18\\D$', None, username, password, 0)
       print('connection established successfully')
   except:
       print('connection not established')
   ```

   To unmount remote computer drive in local system:

   ```
   import win32api
   import win32net
   import win32netcon,win32wnet

   win32wnet.WNetCancelConnection2('\\\\192.168.1.4\\D$',1,1)
   ```

> Before using netuse you should have pywin32 install in your system with python also.

---

Source: [Connect remote system](http://ashishpython.blogspot.in/2013/11/how-to-connect-one-computer-to-another_1.html).

Comment: What is the relative advantages and disadvantages of WMI over Netuse and vice versa?

Answer (score 10):

You can use [`pywinrm` library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pywinrm) instead which is cross-platform compatible.

Here is a simple code example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import winrm

# Create winrm connection.
sess = winrm.Session('https://10.0.0.1', auth=('username', 'password'), transport='kerberos')
result = sess.run_cmd('ipconfig', ['/all'])
```

Install library via: `pip install pywinrm requests_kerberos`.

---

Here is another example from [this page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pywinrm/0.2.2) to run Powershell script on a remote host:

```
import winrm

ps_script = """$strComputer = $Host
Clear
$RAM = WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem
$MB = 1048576

"Installed Memory: " + [int]($RAM.TotalPhysicalMemory /$MB) + " MB" """

s = winrm.Session('windows-host.example.com', auth=('john.smith', 'secret'))
r = s.run_ps(ps_script)
>>> r.status_code
0
>>> r.std_out
Installed Memory: 3840 MB

>>> r.std_err
```

Comment: I was trying this and I am facing an issue when I run a command like 'ipconfig'. It says "HTTPSConnectionPool(host='192.168.1.13', port=5986): Max retries exceeded with url: /wsman (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fcb12024a90>, 'Connection to 192.168.1.13 timed out. (connect timeout=30)'))""

Answer (score 7):

Maybe you can use SSH to connect to a remote server.

Install freeSSHd on your windows server.

SSH Client connection Code:

```
import paramiko

hostname = "your-hostname"
username = "your-username"
password = "your-password"
cmd = 'your-command'

try:
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(hostname,username=username,password=password)
    print("Connected to %s" % hostname)
except paramiko.AuthenticationException:
    print("Failed to connect to %s due to wrong username/password" %hostname)
    exit(1)
except Exception as e:
    print(e.message)    
    exit(2)
```

Execution Command and get feedback:

```
try:
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd)
except Exception as e:
    print(e.message)

err = ''.join(stderr.readlines())
out = ''.join(stdout.readlines())
final_output = str(out)+str(err)
print(final_output)
```

Comment: This solution helped me a big time. From windows machine I was trying to run a shell script on a remote machine which eventually has python script path to run. 
If I need to run multiple commands then can I repeat the execution command box ? Please suggest.

Comment: When you run exec_command multiple times, each command is executed in its own "shell". So the previous commands have no effect on an environment of the following commands.

Comment: If you need the previous commands to affect the following commands, just use an appropriate syntax of your server shell. Most *nix shells use a semicolon or an double-ampersand (with different semantics) to specify a list of commands. In your case, the ampersand is more appropriate, as it executes following commands, only if previous commands succeed:

like this:
stdin,stdout,stderr=ssh.exec_command("ORACLE_SID=PROD && cd /01/application/dataload && pwd")

Answer (score 6):

For connection

```
c=wmi.WMI('machine name',user='username',password='password')

#this connects to remote system. c is wmi object
```

for commands

```
process_id, return_value = c.Win32_Process.Create(CommandLine="cmd.exe /c  <your command>")

#this will execute commands
```

Comment: wow, very cool, work very good, can be install using pip
[#]pip install wmi

Answer (score 2):

do the client machines have python loaded?  if so, I'm doing this with [psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx)

On my local machine, I use subprocess in my .py file to call a command line.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("psexec {server} -c {}")
```

the -c copies the file to the server so i can run any executable file (which in your case could be a .bat full of connection tests or your .py file from above).

Answer (score 2):

I have personally found [`pywinrm` library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pywinrm) to be very effective.  However, it does require some commands to be run on the machine and some other setup before it will work.

Comment: Can u suggest some package that can be used for cross platform remote login

Comment: Funny you should ask. I'm personally working on open sourcing a library for just exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know WMI but if you want a simple Server/Client,
You can use this simple code from [tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_networking.htm)

**Server:**

```
import socket               # Import socket module

s = socket.socket()         # Create a socket object
host = socket.gethostname() # Get local machine name
port = 12345                # Reserve a port for your service.
s.bind((host, port))        # Bind to the port

s.listen(5)                 # Now wait for client connection.
while True:
   c, addr = s.accept()     # Establish connection with client.
   print 'Got connection from', addr
   c.send('Thank you for connecting')
   c.close()                # Close the connection
```

**Client**

```
#!/usr/bin/python           # This is client.py file

import socket               # Import socket module

s = socket.socket()         # Create a socket object
host = socket.gethostname() # Get local machine name
port = 12345                # Reserve a port for your service.

s.connect((host, port))
print s.recv(1024)
s.close                     # Close the socket when done
```

it also have all the needed information for simple client/server applications.

Just convert the server and use some simple protocol to call a function from python.

***P.S: i'm sure there are a lot of better options, it's just a simple one if you want...***

Comment: ***Thank you Kobi for replying me, but this is gonna be so hard to go to every client and run a script there.... what i am trying to do is accessing multiple machines from 1 machine and execute commands there***

Answer (score 1):

The best way to connect to the remote server and execute commands is by using "**wmiexec.py**"

Just run **pip install impacket**

Which will create "**wmiexec.py**" file under the scripts folder in python

Inside the python > Scripts > wmiexec.py

we need to run the wmiexec.py in the following way

```
python <wmiexec.py location> TargetUser:TargetPassword@TargetHostname "<OS command>"
```

Pleae change the wmiexec.py location according to yours

Like im using python 3.8.5 and my wmiexec.py location will be **C:\python3.8.5\Scripts\wmiexec.py**

```
python C:\python3.8.5\Scripts\wmiexec.py TargetUser:TargetPassword@TargetHostname "<OS command>"
```

Modify TargetUser, TargetPassword ,TargetHostname and OS command according to your remote machine

**Note:**
Above method is used to run the commands on remote server.

But if you need to capture the output from remote server we need to create an python code.

```
import subprocess
command = 'C:\\Python36\\python.exe C:\\Python36\\Scripts\\wmiexec.py TargetUser:TargetPassword@TargetHostname "ipconfig"'
command = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout= command.communicate()[0]
print (stdout)
```

Modify the code accordingly and run it.

Answer (score 0):

is it too late?

I personally agree with Beatrice Len, I used paramiko maybe is an extra step for windows, but I have an example project git hub, feel free to clone or ask me.

https://github.com/davcastroruiz/django-ssh-monitor

Answer (score 0):

pypsrp - Python PowerShell Remoting Protocol Client library

```
At a basic level, you can use this library to;

Execute a cmd command
Run another executable
Execute PowerShell scripts
Copy a file from the localhost to the remote Windows host
Fetch a file from the remote Windows host to the localhost
Create a Runspace Pool that contains one or multiple PowerShell pipelines and execute them asynchronously
Support for a reference host base implementation of PSRP for interactive scripts
```

REF: https://github.com/jborean93/pypsrp

Answer (score 0):

Many answers already, but one more option

PyPSExec
https://pypi.org/project/pypsexec/

It's a python clone of the famous psexec.
Works without any installation on the remote windows machine.