# Connection to Remote Machine using python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, remote-server

I am trying to connect to remote machine by python script. Both the machines can be **linux/windows**.

I have to connect to various remote machines and it's not feasible for me to install or write some code on the remote side. I know the ip, username and password of the machine and i tried various options but was unsuccessful.

How shall I proceed.

Comment: Check this out: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18961213/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18961213/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use SSH to connect to a remote server.

paramiko will be good idea, it can use to connect linux/windows.

http://pxnet2768.pixnet.net/blog/post/157228756-%E7%B3%BB%E7%B5%B1%E9%81%8B%E7%B6%AD%E5%B7%A5%E7%A8%8B%E5%B8%AB%E7%9A%84%E6%B3%95%E5%AF%B6%EF%BC%9Apython-paramiko