# check if file exists on remote windows machine in python

Tags: python

I am very new to python and i need to check if file exists on remote windows machine using python .
I have file with name demo.ps1 under c drive on remote windows machine ,is there something in python from which i can check if this file exists on machine

Comment: The remote machine's drive should be accessible from the other PC, for example by creating a share

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check whether a file exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82831/how-do-i-check-whether-a-file-exists)

Answer (score 0):

There's not really any universal cross platform way to check if a file exists remotely, so there's not builtin python modules to do this.  If you have pywin32 installed, there may be ways, however: for instance, try the second method (netuse) mentioned in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20367984/920545