# Is there any way by which I can install pypiwin32 in python version 3.7.1

Tags: pywin32, python-3.7, pypi

I am trying to use wmi or netuse. For which, I need to have pypiwin32 in the path.

[How to connect to a remote Windows machine to execute commands using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18961213/how-to-connect-to-a-remote-windows-machine-to-execute-commands-using-python)

I am trying to achieve close to something like above.Is this package is available for 3.7.1 version of python.

I have tried installing it using 
- pip 
- going to its website 
- cherry package

```
pip install -U  pypiwin32
Collecting pypiwin32
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d0/1b/2f292bbd742e369a100c91faa0483172cd91a1a422a6692055ac920946c5/pypiwin32-223-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pywin32>=223 (from pypiwin32)
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32>=223 (from pypiwin32) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pywin32>=223 (from pypiwin32)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the `pywin32` project has published Python 3.7-compatible releases for [version 223](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/223/#files):

- `pywin32-223-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl`
- `pywin32-223-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl`

and [version 224](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/224/#history):

- `pywin32-224-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl`
- `pywin32-224-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl`

It seems like the platform you're installing from is not compatible with these releases, is it not a Windows machine?

Comment: Oh, Yes. I have realised I am trying to install it on Mac, which caused the trouble. Now, I am on my way to try it on windows machine. Thank you.

Comment: Great to hear. Please accept if this helped answer your question.