# How can I call a file in a remote server through python3?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, remote-server

For example I have a .py script on my computer (Windows Server 2017), and I want to use it to control a remote server (Windows Server 2017) to do the following steps:

1. Open MS Word(which has already been installed) on the remote server
2. Use the word to open a word doc which is located on the remote server too.

Anyone has any brilliant idea? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved here: [How to connect to a remote Windows machine to execute commands using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18961213/how-to-connect-to-a-remote-windows-machine-to-execute-commands-using-python)

Answer (score 0):

Soo, for this case, i would prefer PowerShell to do this task, because powershell has a lot of libs for admin taks, and automatization. And powershell are the language used in windows server, in my job, i use powershell to do some taks, like send an email, create a profile in the server, and other things. Show me the code:

```
$Filename='C:\HappyBirthdayEd.docx' #set the name and location of the file
$Word=NEW-Object –comobject Word.Application #set the word application
$Document=$Word.documents.open($Filename) #open the document
```

So, this little block of code open an word file. Just do some changes and i thing can work.
PS.: Sorry my bad english.

Comment: It's OK to do it by PowerShell, in this case, however my problem is how to use the PowerShell in my computer to control a remote server, to call a Word.Application which is not in the computer your PowerShell command is based in.

Comment: For the Word.Application a don't know yet, but to control the server you can user Invoke-Command, with Credential and ServerName like this:

`Invoke-Command -ComputerName server01 -Credential domain01\user01 -ScriptBlock {Get-Culture}`

In the -ScriptBlock you can put the command you have to use. With Invoke-Command you can create sessions in the server, and other things, check the doc here: 
[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-6)