# Azure python SDK run powershell script inside a Virtual Machine

Tags: python, azure, powershell, sdk

**Summary:** I'm trying to create a python program to run Powershell scripts in Azure Windows VMs. But I can't find good documentation about which libraries of the SDK I can use.

**Detailed:** In order to automate certain administrative tasks, a python program should run, authenticate into Azure and then run Powershell scripts in certain Windows VMs. I think I have the auth part thanks to `azure.identity`, but I can't find any library to interact with a running VM. Sure, lots for creating or modifying a VM in Azure, but nothing to interact with it. Neither in the [SDK](https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk/releases/latest/mgmt/python.html) or in the [API browser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/?view=azure-python). I know it can be done with Azure CLI, but id like to use the SDK, if possible at all.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you would like to run PowerShell remotely using the Python SDK.

AFAIK, I don't think there is a provision within the **Azure Python SDK** to run remote  PS scripts.

**Workaround :**

(But please note that this outside the Azure Python SDK.)

You could create [Azure Windows WinRM VM template](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/resources/templates/201-vm-winrm-windows/) and you could execute ps commands from the Python code using the **winrm library** like discussed in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18961213/how-to-connect-to-a-remote-windows-machine-to-execute-commands-using-python).