# How to make a connection to a remote server like in Teamviewer?

Tags: python, ssh, teamviewer

I want to know is it possible to connect to remote windows server through python and for the clicker to work, for example, when you connect via a standard windows remote connection, then after the connection is closed, the clicker stops working.

I found a solution, it's teamviewer, but I need to run clickers on multiple servers. Can I use python to open the same connections as teamviewer in order for the clicker to work?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

you have the https://www.paramiko.org/ package which allows connecting to machines remotely and running commands on them this best for Ubuntu machines.

If you want to remote connect to windows machines you can try this answer, although i have less experience with this type of remote connection [How to connect to a remote Windows machine to execute commands using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18961213/how-to-connect-to-a-remote-windows-machine-to-execute-commands-using-python)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: yea, your answer imply only connection to client-server and run commands, but I want to connect with graph interface like TeamViewer